# I cannot find my published cube in Pentaho User Console

Tags: pentaho, saiku

I have a problem finding my cubes. I have created my Data WareHouse with Pentaho in a PostgreSQL database. Then, I created my cubes with Schema Workbench just fine and published my cubes successfully, or at least this is what they say when I try to publish them. However, when I go to my User Console, refresh the Mondrian cache and open Saiku I just cannot find my cubes. This is not normal at all. Since I followed the exact steps of some tutorials, but I cannot find my cubes.

I believe that this problem is linked to versions of the technologies that I am using. So, here are the version of each technology:

- Pentaho BI server: 6
- Schema Workbench:3.12.0.1-196

Please advise if they are compatible or not

Comment: Generally, it happen even after getting message of successfully published you may find some errors into a log file.(/biserver-ce/tomcat/logs)

Check pentaho.log,mondrian.log files whether

Comment: Did you found the solution?
Maybe you can see on Manage Data Sources if created some data font. If your cube has been successfully published, then it should appear there.